# How get correct total number of elements of a PByteArray?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

On following code i'm trying convert a binary file to your correspondent bytes representation in Delphi.
I'm with difficulty to get the correct total number of elements of array (declared as `PByteArray`) and this returns a limited number (32767) like already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428195/13342579). Then exists a alternative way to achieve it?

This is code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function File2ByteArray(const FileName: string; out ByteArray: PByteArray): Boolean;
var
  hFile: HWND;
  dwSize, dwRead: DWORD;
begin
  Result := False;
  hFile := CreateFile(PChar(FileName), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  if hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    Exit;
  dwSize := GetFileSize(hFile, nil);
  ByteArray := AllocMem(dwSize);
  ReadFile(hFile, ByteArray^, dwSize, dwRead, nil);
  Result := True;
  CloseHandle(hFile);
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ByteArray: PByteArray;
  MyList: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if File2ByteArray(ParamStr(0), ByteArray) then
  begin
    try
      MyList := TStringList.Create;
      MyList.Add('Const');
      MyList.Add('  aSize = ' + IntToStr(High(ByteArray^)) + ';');
      MyList.Add('stub_: Array [' + IntToStr(Low(ByteArray^)) + ' .. ' + IntToStr(High(ByteArray^) - 1) + '] of Byte =');
      MyList.Add('(');
      MyList.Add('');

      for I := Low(ByteArray^) to High(ByteArray^) - 1 do
        MyList.Add('$' + IntToHex(ByteArray[I], 2) + ',');

      MyList.Add(');');

      MyList.SaveToFile('C:\File2ByteArray.txt');
    finally
      MyList.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Off topic, but very important: `MyList := TStringList.Create;` **MUST** be the line *before* `try`. As it is now, if the constructor raises an exception, you will do `MyList.Free` where `MyList` is a random pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to an array allocated as you have done so, does not contain length information. You cannot query that pointer for the length of the array. Instead you need to modify `File2ByteArray` so that it returns that length, in addition to the pointer.

We can't see what type `PByteArray` is, but I would normally expect to see `PByte` used to represent a pointer to an array of bytes.

It's also worth noting that your code leaks the array. I would resolve that, and resolve the issue of length, by returning a `TBytes` dynamic array instead of a manually allocated array.

Comment: The total array elements is equal to file size, in othres words = `dwSize` or `dwRead`, right?

Comment: *`"It's also worth noting that your code leaks the array."`* - i think that forgot `FreeMem(ByteArray)` after save `MyList` :D, thank you.

Comment: You allocated the array! You knew how large it was when you allocated it. That's how large it is.

Comment: @Davison `dwSize` is the total file size that you allocate (though you are not checking `GetFileSize()` for failure), while `dwRead` is the number of bytes that are actually read into the memory you allocated, and may be less than `dwSize` (since you are not checking `ReadFile()` for failure, or a partial read). `ReadFile()` is not required or guaranteed to return the exact requested number of bytes in a single operation, you need a loop to ensure you get all of the bytes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you by these guidelines. I will follow they.